# how to use split() function in classic ASP for mass inputs textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, asp-classic

I am trying to use the split function in classic ASP using JavaScript. I need to have a big text box where I can keep group of bar-code numbers of products. Once submit button is clicked These bar-code numbers needed to be split by each and every character term for all bar-code numbers (in a loop). For instance, if i have 5 bar-code numbers, I have to split first bar-code number by each and every character/number, keep into array and continue same process to all 5 bar-code numbers. I wanted to display the result of split-ted numbers into a paragraph for myself just to check if its working. Below is the code I was working on. It doesn't show me anything when i click the button. I am not being able to figure out my logical error or what am I missing. How do I fix it? I didn't find any helpful solution when i was doing research.

```
    <p id="demo"></p> 
        <form name="submitticket" action="<%=Request("script_name")%>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendform">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <br /><textarea name="noskews" id="skewsip" rows="50" cols="100" wrap="soft" maxlength="5000"><%=Request("noskews")%></textarea> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;">
                    <input type="submit" name="clearNoskew" value="Submit" class="a-t-button-mini">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    <script>
        $("form").on("click", ".a-t-button-mini", function(event){
          //var clickedId = $(this).attr('value')+','; // give me first numbers,
          var locationBtn = $('#skewsip'); // Select the input
          var locationBtnValue = $('#skewsip').val(); // Take the select value
          var ids = locationBtnValue.split(','); 
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ids; //want to display in a paragraph for myself
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Few questions, the code sort of implies that the barcodes will be separated by a comma.  Is that true?  Also, you are getting a button `var locationBtn = $('#btnclear');` and button value `var locationBtnValue = $('#btnclear').val();`, but that button doesn't exist in the html.  Also also, you are reading the barcodes from the button value(?) and not the textarea, where I would expect the barcodes to be.  Third also, you are setting the result (that isn't getting a value to set to it anywhere) to a demo element that is commented out.  You're having a bad day :)

Comment: 1. Barcodes is just 12 digits numbers. 2. I just have one button. i.e <input type="submit" name="clearNoskew" value="Submit" class="a-t-button-mini">. var locationBtn and locationBtnValue are just variables I created thinking I might have to select every bar-code for splitting. I tried keeping textbox name i.e #skewsip instead of #btnclear  in there but i didn't get any output. 3. that one was my mistake for commenting :) I am going to edit it.

Comment: So every 12 characters would be a new barcode?

Comment: no they are inputted by me. I mean in a textbox, I will just type them. I just need to 1.grab contents of textbox. 2. Go through it one by one or split them one by one 3. Put it in array, split by character term 4. Go to all bar-codes repeat same. 5. Display result somewhere. like paragraph or div. It might be easy but I am new to classic asp and javascript so its taking me forever to figure it out

Comment: I still can't tell: how are the barcodes separated from each other? Maybe you could give us a sample of the contents of the textbox?

Comment: 087002112713
011434008112
635824055116
354988090484 after typing one barcode just enter and type another barcode These can be either typed or just copy and paste them into this textarea.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to split one barcode (out of total 5 barcodes entered inside textarea) by every characters and display it into div. for example: I entered 5465  8989 7586 5236 5486 (These barcodes are entered using "enter or new line" after every 4 numbers; space in above example means the next barcode is in next line). I get split output of (5,4,6,5) which I need but it didn't give me for rest of my barcodes. In other words, I couldn't do same for all 5 total bar codes entered into the textarea/textbox. I know its only "for loop" When I kept for loop in my code, it executes for first barcode out of 5 barcodes.

```
<script>
$("#form").on("click",".a-t-button-mini", function(event){
    var locationBtnValue = $('#skewsip').val();
    var skews_array = locationBtnValue.split("",12);
     // for (i = 0; i < locationBtnValue.length; i++) {
    //      text += skews_array[i] + "<br>";
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = skews_array;
       //  }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying each barcode on a new line of the textarea.  If so, this should work for you (\n is the newline character), at least to capture and re-output to the demo element:

```
<script>
    $("form").on("click", ".a-t-button-mini", function(event){
      var ids = $("#noskews").val().split('\n'); 
      $.each( ids, function( index, value ) {
        $("#demo").append(index + ' - ' + value + '<br/>');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Added working code to codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxENYW

Comment: Since your button is a type of "submit", it's probably submitting the form and refreshing the page.  You can either change your input type to "button", which should stop it from submitting.  Or you could try putting this in the javascript method to stop the default behavior of submitting `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: When I used the code as you mentioned above, it did split for first barcode only. Not for all total 5 barcodes I had entered into the textarea control. can you please tell me how can i split all barcodes?

Comment: Were all of the barcodes each on a separate line?  (IE: separated by \n)

Comment: yes they are in separate lines. one can just copy and paste the barcodes or type them but they are in separate lines

Comment: Actually, each of the bar code need to be kept in array then split by character term. Then, check for all 5 barcodes. Basically, one barcode = 1 array. All barcodes should have different array. Then just loop for remaining 4 barcodes. Is it possible to do?

Comment: There are various ways to do it, but you know each barcode has 12 characters.  You can use each array entry as a type of array.  I updated the codepen to show each character of each barcode separate.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxENYW